# Toggleswitch size in xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, toggleswitch

How do I change the size of the actual switch in ToggleSwitch in xaml?  I can change the text size for the OnContent and OffContent, but the sliding switch never changes size.

None of these change the size of the switch itself, but just the box around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change this you need to edit the ToggleSwitch template for the ToggleSwitch default style.

I find this easiest to do in Blend For Visual Studio 2012.

- Open Blend and right-click the toggleswitch in the designer.
- Pick the **Edit Template\Edit a Copy...** context menu.

[image]

- In the Objects and Timeline,look through the template element for a likely element.  In this case it is the **SwitchKnobBounds** element.
- Now that you've found the change the settings.  In this case you can drag the sizing handles.
  [image]
- When you are happy with the edited changed, click the scope out button at the top of the editor to return to normal edit mode.
  [image]

Here is the resulting XAML from the edit.

```
    <Style x:Key="ToggleSwitchStyle1" TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="154"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchCurtain">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchCurtainPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchCurtain">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchCurtainPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchHeaderDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchOuterBorderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchCurtain">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchCurtainDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ToggleStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOnTransition" From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" To="On">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainCurrentToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOffTransition" From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" To="Off">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainCurrentToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OnToOffTransition" From="On" GeneratedDuration="0" To="Off">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobOnToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainOnToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OffToOnTransition" From="Off" GeneratedDuration="0" To="On">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobOffToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainOffToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Dragging"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Off">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-44" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="CurtainTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="On">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="CurtainTranslateTransform"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="38" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ContentStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="OffContent">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OnContent">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}" FontWeight="Semilight" Margin="6"/>
                            <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="OffContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OffContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding OffContent}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="6,5,0,16" MinWidth="65" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="OnContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OnContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding OnContent}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="6,5,0,16" MinWidth="65" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="2">
                                    <Grid x:Name="SwitchKnobBounds" Height="42" Margin="13,5,13,16">
                                        <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchOuterBorderBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="2">
                                            <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTrackBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTrackBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="SwitchCurtainBounds">
                                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="SwitchCurtainClip">
                                                        <Rectangle x:Name="SwitchCurtain" Fill="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchCurtainBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="44">
                                                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="CurtainTranslateTransform" X="-44"/>
                                                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                                        </Rectangle>
                                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                                </ContentPresenter>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="SwitchKnob" Fill="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stroke="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="12">
                                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
                                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                        </Rectangle>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" Margin="-3" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" Margin="-3" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="SwitchThumb">
                                        <Thumb.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                                <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Thumb.Template>
                                    </Thumb>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ToggleSwitch Header='ToggleSwitch' 
                                HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                                Margin='795,165,0,0'
                                VerticalAlignment='Top'
                                Height='120' />
    <ToggleSwitch Header='ToggleSwitch'
                                HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                                Margin='203,165,0,0'
                                VerticalAlignment='Top' Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchStyle1}" />

</Grid>
```

This is the relevant XAML in the template.

```
<Grid x:Name="SwitchKnobBounds" Height="42" Margin="13,5,13,16">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can scale it.

```
<ToggleSwitch>
    <ToggleSwitch.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform ScaleX=".5" ScaleY=".5"/>
    </ToggleSwitch.RenderTransform>
</ToggleSwitch>
```

Comment: This was so easy and unexpected ! should be the answer